# Android Achievement Animation/View

Tags: android, achievements

is it possible to show a achievement like google play does without it? I would like to create a "Welcome back " banner, when my app is starting.

[image]

In Android Ultimate you can create a achievement using:

```
AchievementUnlocked test = new AchievementUnlocked(YourActivity.this).setTitle("Title").setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.gpg)).setSubTitle("Subtitle").build().show();
```

Thanks for all results!

Comment: You can always use a `Toast` message. http://www.materialdoc.com/toast/

Comment: But a toast wont look so cute :(

Comment: You can style a toast, read the documentation

Comment: but it wont have such a nice animation :D